# Is there any way to specify a specific user when auditing a Model?

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-auditing

**Expected Behaviour**

I'm auditing the Product model currently but I just want to audit the model when a specific user makes any change, is there any way I could achieve this?

**Possible Solutions**

It would be great if the Developer get the control to set the particular set of userID on Model as

`protected $user_ids = [1,2,3]`;

- Framework | **Laravel**
- Framework version | **7.x**
- Package Name | **owen-it/laravel-auditing**
- Package version | **11.0**
- PHP version | **7.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try listening for the auditing event, `OwenIt\Auditing\Events\Auditing`, that this package fires off. You could check what you need to at that point and return `false` from the listener if you want it to not do the audit.

Comment: Will try this and let you know.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. and if someone else faces the same issue you can make a listener and register it to EventServiceProvider with `OwenIt\Auditing\Events\Auditing` like this `Auditing::class => [\App\Listeners\AuditingListener::class]`